# How to setup conditionals within a matrix?

Tags: matrix

In my matrix field, I want to be able to upload my image, and then upload another asset (in this case it would be a document) so that that image I upload links to that document.

I have my Matrix field setup like so:

Image ->
  -Image
  -linkedDocument

How can I set up a conditional where only add in the  tag *if* I add an asset there?

Here is my relevant code:

```
% elseif block.type == "image" %}

        {% set image = block.image.first() %}

        {% if image %}
            <a href="{{ image.linkedDocument }}"><img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('thumb') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('thumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `image`, you want to display it, and if there is also a `linkedDocument`, you want the `image` to link to that document. This should handle both cases, without too much code duplication.

```
{% if block.type == "image" %}

  {% set image = block.image.first %}

  {% if image %}
    {# set the imgTag, which we will display regardless #}
    {% set imgTag %}
      <img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('thumb') }}"  height="{{ image.getHeight('thumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></a> alt="{{ image.title }}">
    {% endset %}

    {% set linkedDocument = block.linkedDocument.first %}

    {# we may or may not have a linkedDocument. Display the image in either case #}
    {% if linkedDocument %}
      <a href="{{ linkedDocument.url }}">{{imgTag}}</a>
    {% else %}
      {{imgTag}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is just another reason why I love the Craft CMS community. Thanks so much Marion!

Answer (score 2):

Very close. It just looks like you are trying to reference the 'linkedDocument' through 'image' instead of through the block, and you are not retrieving the url.

```
{% if block.type == "image" %}

    {% set image = block.image.first %}
    {% set document = block.linkedDocument.first %}

    {% if image %}
        {% if document %}<a href="{{ document.url }}">{% endif %}<img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('thumb') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('thumb') }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">{% if document %}</a>{% endif %}
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Update: Added conditional for `if document`. Essentially the same answer as Marion's.

Comment: How do I handle the case if there is no linked document? I want to be able to put in images without linked doucments and images with linked documents.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't get that part from your question. Looks like Marion has an answer for you.